# EventToCommandBehavior for DataGridView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagridview, datagrid, eventtocommand

I need EventToCommandBehavior for DataGridView.

```
<pages:PopupPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedEventArgsConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</pages:PopupPage.Resources>
 <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Liste}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="ItemTapped"
                    Command="{Binding ListeTapCommand}"
                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}"
                    
                    />
                </ListView.Behaviors>
        </ListView>
```

I can use EventToCommandBehavior for a normal listview but when i try to use for DataGridView i couldn't find any EventArgsConverter for Datagridview.
How can i handle this issue ?

Thanks for Jason i could write my own converter.

**Solution :**
You need a new class for event args :

```
 public class DataGridGestureEventArgsConverter : BaseNullableConverterOneWay<DataGridGestureEventArgs, object>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts/Extracts the incoming value from <see cref="DataGridGestureEventArgs"/> object and returns the value of <see cref="DataGridGestureEventArgs.Item"/> property from it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DataGridGestureEventArgs.Item"/> object from object of type <see cref="DataGridGestureEventArgs"/>.</returns>
    public override object ConvertFrom(DataGridGestureEventArgs value) => value?.Item;
}
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:YourApp.Data"

 <pages:PopupPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedEventArgsConverter"/>
        <data:DataGridGestureEventArgsConverter x:Key="DataGridGestureEventArgsConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</pages:PopupPage.Resources>

<dxg:DataGridView.Behaviors>
                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="Tap"
                    Command="{Binding ListeTapCommand}"
                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource DataGridGestureEventArgsConverter}"/>
            </dxg:DataGridView.Behaviors>
```

It works well like this.

Comment: write your own - https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Converters/ItemTappedEventArgsConverter.shared.cs

Comment: if I change ItemTappedEventArgs with datagridview event args is this new class work as I want ?